# Setup for heavy rider and DB 29" overdrive

Tags: bike-setup, heavy, clydesdale

As a heavy rider (~135kg 300lbs), I got a Diamondback Overdrive 29" bike to help me lose weight.
After riding a few times with my family, my rear wheel keeps deflating/bursting. 
I have read previous posts on here and inflated the rear wheel more than was set up yet the issue still remains.
Upon checking the bike specs, it states that the max weight is 100kg .
Can I continue to use this bike but change my set up (different tunes, pressure..) or do I need to buy 'another' bike?
Please help as it's frustrating to get 3/4 through a ride before getting a flat.

Comment: What are the trail/road conditions like?  Are they paved roads, graded gravel paths or are you off trail bombing over logs, boulders etc? What tire pressure are you riding on? Are you repairing the tube or replacing it?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Jay. Good to see you've taken the [tour] :-) This other [question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/38801/8273) may be useful. Regarding losing weight, a 40 minute ride before breakfast can help men lose weight; it doesn't work the same for women. Be careful not to overdo it.

Comment: Next time you get a flat, take the bike (or just the wheel) to a bike shop and have them fix the flat and tell you what caused it.  Likely you are not running high enough pressure in your rear wheel.  The only real weight limitation is that, given your style of riding, the front suspension should not bottom out except in rare situations.

Comment: Could you tell us more please...  Use the EDIT link to expand your question.   Do you patch the tubes or is it tubeless ?    If tubes, are the holes always in a similar place compared to the valve stem ?   Do you ride roads or off-road?  Do you jump kerbs and potholes or do you thump through them?   What tyre pressures are you putting in before your ride?   What width of tyre is on the wheel?

Answer (score 5):

Manufacturer weight limits on bikes are a little nebulous in that they're not totally meaningless but they tend towards estimation, liability protection, and a fair line for the warranty department to take when a bike eventually breaks under a heavier load then they designed for. Going above it is an at your own risk thing because forks, wheels, and frames failing are all real and dangerous things that are only going to be at greater risk of happening as a result. In practical terms though, those kinds of worst case scenarios don't happen very much as a result of exceeding weight limits on non-exotic mountain bikes by this much.

What is at pretty good likelihood of happening is the wheels not really holding up over time. The usual case is for heavier MTB riders that ride a lot to burn through the stock wheels pretty quickly and then get something with a heavier weight rim, ideally handbuilt and with 36 spokes. If you want to, it could be reasonable to skip the step of tacoing the rims that came on it or dealing with them going out of true repeatedly and just upgrade now.

As for the flats, you don't say what's causing them, which suggests some odds that it's one of the common causes of repeat flats and not related to weight. The really common ones are a rim strip that's not doing its job, something lodged in the tire, or tires/tubes that aren't puncture resistant enough for where you're riding.

If you're pinch flatting, the main remedy is more pressure, and failing that more width.

Comment: I suspect that following this excellent advice will soon lead to discussing better tyres with your bike shop. You might want something that can take a lot of pressure for its width, for example, or anti-puncture tyres.

Comment: I figure that "tacoing" is a typo but I can't work out what it should be.

Comment: @DavidRicherby tacoing is not a typo.  that is when the wheel buckles really badly, and ends up folded, like a taco (Mexican / American food item)

Comment: @Criggie Ah. Well that's news to me and I suspect it'll be news to a lot of new riders. An explanation in the answer would be useful (or just using the ordinary word "buckling").

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have put too much info into this comment, so its now a whole answer [over here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/44937/19705)

Comment: @Criggie Awesome! Thanks for that! (+2)